# SendGrid email doesn't work on Production

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, sendgrid

I'm using SendGrid Web to send emails with PDF attachments in a ASP.NET MVC web site with C#. Web site is hosted in Windows Azure, as an Azure Web Site.

Everything works very well on my local development machine and in the Test site which is also hosted in Azure.

However I find it very annoying because the same setup doesn't work in the production site. It uses the same username and password for SendGrid and it doesn't work.

My code is something similar to following:

```
public static void SendEmail(string toEmail, string messageHtml)
{
    var message = new SendGridMessage();
    message.From = new MailAddress("me@mydomain.com", "Test Email");
    message.AddTo(toEmail);
    message.Subject = subject;
    message.Html = messageHtml;
    var credentials = new NetworkCredential("mysendgriduser", "mysendgridpassword");
    var transportweb = new SendGrid.Web(credentials);

    try
    {
        transportweb.DeliverAsync(message).Wait();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Or it simply just doesn't work?

Comment: FYI, `Sendgrid.Web.Web` has a synchronous `.Deliver(...)` method. That `.DeliverAsync(...).Wait()` is bothering me.

Comment: Can you provide more detail than "doesn't work"? Is an exception thrown? If so what is it? Include the exception message, inner exception (if any) and stacktrace. Also, do not `throw e` as that generates a new exception of that type and kills the stacktrace. If you aren't going to do anything with a catch block other than throwing it, then there isn't a point in having a try/catch at all.

Comment: @valverij DeliverAsync works perfectly in other Azure environment.

Comment: @user1666620 I agree with your point I'm still trying catch the exception, I will post the details once I get it. But what bothers me is same code works in other environments, how could it fail in a this particular environment? I believe that exception that we are gonna catch holds lot of answers.

Comment: @Geethanga I'm not saying that `DeliverAsync().Wait()` won't technically work, but the API developers thought to include the synchronous `Deliver`. When working with API's that provide both, I recommend using the appropriate, API-provided method call rather than forcing the other to work the way you want it. Plus, you never know what those methods are doing internally that you are bypassing.

Comment: Did you found something?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that Azure stops outbound traffic on particular ports to prevent spamming.  SendGrid recommend port 587.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer,